# Is there a way to arrange buttons in circular pattern inside table?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I have 8 different buttons, I want to arrange them in circular pattern inside table in scene 2D but I don't find any method to do so, All I can do is to arrange them in rows and columns, But that doesn't make it look ciruclar.

Answer (score 0):

In the libgdx-utils package there is a class called CircularGroup which might be what you're looking for

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/libgdx-utils